# Filtrar tabela com vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou usando vue-multiselect para filtrar um calendário usando vue-cal e estou com problemas para filtrar uma tabela com esse seletor. Acredito que o problema seja  filtrar a tabela com um array de dados, por exemplo: filtrar a tabela pelo nome de dois professores. O que eu tenho: 
Quando é selecionado algum professor, eu tenho isso aqui:

```
[{teacher: "Ana"}, {teacher: "Danielly}]
```

E eu tento filtrar assim:

```
filteredEvent() {
     return this.events.filter(events => {
        return events.teacher.toLowerCase().
        indexOf(this.value.forEach(el => el.teacher.toLowerCase() > -1))
    })
}
```

O slot de eventos do calendário está assim:

```
<template slot="event-renderer" v-for="events in filteredEvent" slot-scope="{event, view}">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="event-content" :style="{border: event.border,}">
        <div class="vuecal__event-title">
            <div class="level-color" :style="{background: event.color}"></div>
            <m-avt-level pClass="table__avt-icon" class="centered-icon" :level="event.level" />
            <p class="title">{{event.level}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vuecal__event-time mt-2">
            {{event.time}}
        </div>
        <div class="vuecal__event-bar mt-1 mb-2">
            <b-container>
                <m-progress-bar :animated="                 
           :occupedVacancys=" parseInt(event.occupedVacancys) "                                          
           :maxVacancys="parseInt(event.maxVacancys) "/>
          </b-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o select:

```
   <multiselect
       v-model="value"
       :options="options"
       :multiple="true"
       :close-on-select="false"
       track-by="teacher"
       :custom-label="customLabel">
            <span class="checkbox-label" slot="option" slot-scope="scope" @click.self="select(scope.option)">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="scope.option.selected" @focus.prevent/>
                {{ scope.option.teacher }}
            </span>
            <span slot="placeholder" slot-scope="scope">
            <svgicon icon="icn_teacher" class="filter-icon" width="18" height="auto" color="#959BA6" />
                Todos os professores
            </span>
</multiselect>
```

E o objeto this.events:

```
border: "2px solid #3057a5"
class: "ap3"
classDay: 2
classId: ""
color: "#3057a5"
end: "2019-05-29"
level: "Aperfeiçoamento 3"
levelId: 8
maxVacancys: 1
occupedVacancys: 0
start: "2019-05-29"
teacher: "Danielle Kelley"
time: "00:00 - 01:05"
title: ""
```

Comment: De onde vem `this.events`? qual é a relação entre o professor e a array de eventos? como compará-los?

Comment: this.events é o data que eu uso pra popular o calendário, e dentro desse array de eventos tem o professor que dará a aula em cada horário. Então tipo eu preciso comparar o professor do select com os professores de cada horário

Comment: Eu não coloquei todo o código porque achei que ficaria gigante rs, mas eu posso colocar também

Comment: _"o professor do select "_ .... podes colocar esse select e um objeto como exemplo de `this.events`?

Comment: Coloquei o código do select e um exemplo do this.events

Comment: E que valores podem ser dados ao `this.value`? é uma array com a mesma string `teacher` que na array que tens na pergunta?

Comment: Isso, o que vem no `this.value` é o array com a mesma string de `teacher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o teu Select seta o `this.value` com uma array de valores que corresponde ao valor da chave `teacher` da array de eventos, então esse computed pode ser feito assim:

```js
filteredEvent() {
  return this.events.filter(({teacher}) => this.value.includes(teacher));
}
```

Se `this.value` for uma array de objetos como por exemplo `[{teacher: "Ana"}, {teacher: "Danielly"}]` então podes usar o `.find()` para encontrar esse valor assim:

```js
filteredEvent() {
  return this.events.filter(({teacher}) => this.value.find(obj => obj.teacher === teacher));
}
```

Nota: eu evito usar `value` como chave no `data` de uma instância. Porque é pouco descritivo na maioria dos casos, e porque internamente o Vue usa `value` na lógica/magia do `v-model`.

Comment: Bom saber, vou evitar então usar `value` de agora em diante. Eu acredito que entendi o que você fez aí, mas te passei algo errado rs na verdade o select seta o `this.value` como um array de objetos, e a chave desse objeto é a string que corresponde a chave `teacher`. Por exemplo `[{teacher: "Ana"}, {teacher: "Danielly"}]`

Comment: @FelipeJardim editei a resposta

Comment: Perfeito! Agora preciso dar uma olhada e entender essa sintaxe `this.events.filter(({teacher})`rs mas obrigado mesmo, estava a um tempo preso nisso

Comment: @FelipeJardim essa sintaxe é JavaScript moderno, mas basicamente `({teacher})` é o mesmo que `obj` e depois fazeres `const teacher = obj.teacher`. Ou seja um atalho para extrair diretamente uma chave do objeto que a função recebe.